# Automated Selenium HTML tests in Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, junit, automated-tests

I'm trying to find a way how to completely automate the Selenium tests in Jenkins.

My whole idea:
I want to record a test with the Selenium IDE. Then save the test as the HTML code. Put the HTML file as e.g. test1.test on the server with Jenkins. Jenkins should do the test from the information of the HTML file.

The last sentence is now the problem. I can't find a simple way to convert the HTML file into a possible JUnit test and just run it.

I found selenese4j and the idea is nice but it's returning just the tests itself. Is there a simple way to tell Jenkins to use selenese4j to convert from HTML to a JUnit test and then run the JUnit test?

I know that it is possible to use a dynamic wrapper to run the tests but it's more than just a simple and easy way.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Selenium Webdriver.
If you have not enough skill, just export Selenium IDE code as Java or any language, build it by Jenkins and run.

Comment: So why can't you export it Selenium IDE code to Java?

Comment: I want that people who can't understand Java are able to add and modify tests and that is with the simple HTML code possible.

Comment: Also Geb would be an idean but the Selenium IDE can't export to geb code